# How to pass a numeric value into a function that requires pointer value in C

Tags: c

My function is `void x(int *y);`

I want to call it like `x(&6);` or `x({6});`,  I do not want to define an integer and assign 6 to it, I want single line.

Comment: Totally unclear. Elaborate a bit or the question will be closed as unclear soon

Comment: C is not Fortran. C is not Fortran. C is not Fortran.

Comment: _I want single line..._ why? Is this a homework question?

Comment: This question is unanswerable and should be closed. It is impossible to pass a variable without defining one. A compound literal will still define a variable (an integer), which is initialized by some integer value. Having a single line has nothing to do with variables. You can have the entire program on the same line and it'll be valid.

Comment: @2501: I believe a compound literal *is* what OP is asking for, regardless of what it's functionally equivalent to.

Comment: @bub no this is not homework.  But what if it was a hw question???

Comment: @Groo If you have to *believe* (read as: assume, or interpret vague statements) what op is asking, then the correct action is to vote to close.

Comment: _But what if it was a hw question???_ We are not here for doing your homework. Visit [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @2501: Most newbie questions need to be "interpreted" in some way or another. So, let me rephrase: As I *understood* it, a compound literal is what OP asked for. Two other answerers understood the question this way. Even you did also, since you mentioned compound literals in your comment. But if there is some other way to interpret this question, please share it.

Comment: @Groo *Most newbie questions need to be "interpreted" in some way or another.* Do you have any statistic for that claim? But let's assume what you're saying is true. Most questions coming from new users fall under one of the reasons to close. Does that absolve them from closure. Absolutely not.

Comment: (cont...) Closure is not determined by the status of the asker, but solely by the contents of the question.

Comment: *Even you did also, since you mentioned compound literals in your comment.* That's quote mining and adding content where there is none. I mentioned compound literals in a specific context, and you're dropping that context and asserting that I did so because I understood the question. The part you're referring to actually argues the opposite.  I was responding to two answers by leaving a comment to OP, and arguing that even assuming OP did mean compound literals, they don't answer the question as they contradict it. Thus showing how vague it is.

Comment: @2501: mystery resolved, the answerers really understood the question correctly, OP got his answer, other people will also benefit from this information. A couple of more close votes from people who find the question unclear and then absolutely everyone profits.

Comment: Why a single line? And `int temp=6; x(&temp);` **is** a single line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is [compound literals](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Compound-Literals.html)

```
#include <stdio.h>

void x(const int *y)
{
    printf("%d\n", *y);
}

int main(void)
{
    x(&(int){6});

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's weird, and it seems I have one, too. :/

Answer (score 3):

This can be done using compound literals:

```
x((int []){6});
```

or somewhat simpler:

```
x(&(int){6});
```

The called function, of course, can make no assumptions about the longevity of the pointed-to data, since it will be gone by the time the call returns.

Comment: +1 It's also useful to mention that a compound literal's lifetime is no better than a temporary variable in that same scope. The function will still be dealing with a pointer to a stack address.